# How to subtract different columns from each other in a dataframe based on a condition

Tags: r

In my dataframe for my university project i have to subtract the true_date from the year renovated, if the house was never renovated then it should be subtracted from yr_built.

Here is a small extract

```
   yr_built yr_renovated  true_date
1      1995            0 2014-12-30
2      2006            0 2014-09-12
3      2008            0 2014-07-24
4      1973            0 2014-08-01
5      1998            0 2015-02-25
6      1971            0 2014-10-09
7      2004            0 2014-08-18
8      1954            0 2014-06-20
9      1977            0 2014-08-22
10     1968            0 2015-01-08
11     1924            0 2015-03-03
12     1953            0 2015-04-28
13     1941         1998 2014-08-14
```

I first converted the true date into a date using as.Date then extracted the years into an object called yr_sold.

```
  House_Data$true_date <- as.Date(House_Data$true_date,na.mr=TRUE)
    yr_sold <-  as.numeric(format(House_Data$true_date, "%Y"))
```

The part where im stuck on is how would i write a condition for it to subtract yr_sold from yr_renovated when yr_renovated > 0 or from yr_built when yr_renovated <= 0

```
for(i in 1:yr_sold) {
    if(House_Data$yr_renovated <= 0) {
        yr_since_renovations <- yr_sold - House_Data$yr_built
}   else {
        yr_since_renovations <- yr_sold-House_Data$yr_renovated
    }
}
```

this is what i wrote for it and it seems to work but R warns me that there were 50 or more warnings.
Are there any better suggestions on how to do this?

```
summary(yr_since_renovations)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00   19.00   42.00   43.11   62.00  115.00
```

We also had to create a summary of yr_since_renovations and it was strongly hinted that something would be odd about it but i do not see anything so im wondering if my code has a mistake in it.

EDIT

After fixing the code i found 2 negative results that need to be removed. I saw that there were negative values in `yr_since_renovation` and the rows that caused `yr_since_renovation` need to be removed from my dataset.

`House_Data <- House_Data[!(years_since_renovation < 0),]`

This is what i tried and it does seem to remove the 2 negative values but when i run `years_since_renovation <- with(House_Data, true_date_year - ifelse(yr_renovated == 0, yr_built, yr_renovated))` to update the variable  i receive this error `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Answer (score 3):

Get the year from `true_date` and subtract the values using `ifelse`

```
df$true_date <- as.Date(df$true_date)
df$true_date_year <- as.integer(format(df$true_date, "%Y"))
with(df, true_date_year - ifelse(yr_renovated == 0, yr_built, yr_renovated))
#[1] 19  8  6 41 17 43 10 60 37 47 91 62 16
```

**data**

```
df <-  structure(list(yr_built = c(1995L, 2006L, 2008L, 1973L, 1998L, 
1971L, 2004L, 1954L, 1977L, 1968L, 1924L, 1953L, 1941L), yr_renovated = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1998L), true_date = structure(c(9L, 
7L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 4L), .Label = c("2014-06-20", 
"2014-07-24", "2014-08-01", "2014-08-14", "2014-08-18", "2014-08-22", 
"2014-09-12", "2014-10-09", "2014-12-30", "2015-01-08", "2015-02-25", 
"2015-03-03", "2015-04-28"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much this worked perfectly and i got a different result for my summary , saw that there were 2 negative values as well as having different observations counts in table() would you be able to explain to me why my code got incorrect values when yours got the correct ones?

Comment: @JDkreyfelt the main reason I think in `for` loop , you are looping over each value  using the `i` index but you are not using the `i` index at all inside the loop. For example, the `if` condition should be `if(House_Data$yr_renovated[i]....`. similarly, `yr_sold[i] - House_Data$yr_built[i]` and so on. However, as shown in the answer in this case you don't need a `for` loop.

Comment: @JDkreyfelt Can you show what is `years_since_renovation` ? I am suspecting `nrow(df)` and `length(years_since_renovation)` are not same.

Comment: I figured what i was getting wrong, i forgot to rerun`true_date_year <- as.integer(format(House_Data$true_date, "%Y"))` with `years_since_renovation <- with(House_Data, true_date_year - ifelse(yr_renovated == 0, yr_built, yr_renovated))` after the removal of the 2 negative values. I originally just ran the `years_since_renovation`